# Centralize logs from Python and NodeJS thanks to RabbitMQ

Tags: python, logging, rabbitmq, pika

I have a service using NodeJS, RabbitMQ and Python workers. The NodeJS brokers use MongoDB and the Python workers have only a connection to the rabbitMQ server.

I would like to be able to centralize all the logs from the different languages in a db.

My idea was to push all the logs in a rabbitMQ queue and then push them in the mongoDB used by NodeJS.

I would like to know if this is the best way to have centralized log and how can I redirect the logging python module to a pika consumer?

Comment: I this it is the better way, but I don't understand what you mean for " how can I redirect the logging python module to a pika consumer?" 
you said that the python worker have a connection with RMQ.

Comment: The workers use pika to receive and send message to RabbitMQ, but I don't know what to do to redirect the logging.error/debug/waring to RabbitMQ.

Comment: This is one of good approach of handling huge number of logs using rabbit MQ. Refer : http://www.infoq.com/articles/event-tracking-rabbitmq-fautsch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a custom [logging.Handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#handler-objects). You would override the `emit` method, and have it publish the log message to a RabbitMQ queue of your choosing. You'll also need to override `close`, and have it close the RabbitMQ channel/connection, etc.

Then to use the handler, do something like this (see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html for more info):

```
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

# create RabbitMQ handler
rh = RabbitMQHandler()  # You need to create this.

# add rh to logger
logger.addHandler(rh)

# start logging stuff
logger.error("An error!")
```

Answer (score 3):

python's [Logbook library](http://pythonhosted.org/Logbook/) has a [RabbitMQHandler](http://pydoc.net/Python/Logbook/0.4.1/logbook.queues/) built into it, so rather than having to write your own, you could probably just use it to redirect logs from your workers back into the RabbitMQ exchange.

Comment: It was renamed to `MessageQueueHandler` because it can handle any message server supported by [kombu](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/introduction.html#transport-comparison): amqp, qpid, zookeeper, mongodb...

Answer (score 2):

This is custom python logging Handler for RabbitMQ which I had written. I had inherited Handler class and had overridden emit and close methods. I used Kombu as python library to access RabbiMQ

```
import logging

class RabbitMQHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
     A handler that acts as a RabbitMQ publisher
     Requires the kombu module.

     Example setup::

        handler = RabbitMQHandler('amqp://guest:guest@localhost//', queue='my_log')
    """
    def __init__(self, uri=None, queue='logging'):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        try:
            import kombu
        except ImportError:
            raise RuntimeError('The Kombu library is required for the RabbitMQSubscriber.')
        if uri:
            connection = kombu.Connection(uri)

        self.queue = connection.SimpleQueue(queue)

    def emit(self, record):
        self.queue.put(record.msg)

    def close(self):
        self.queue.close()
```

Usage :

```
# our own logger
my_logger = logging.getLogger('teja_logger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# rabbitmq handler
rabbitmq_handler = RabbitMQHandler('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//', queue = 'log_q')

# adding rabbitmq handler
my_logger.addHandler(rabbitmq_handler)
my_logger.debug('hello')
```